# Why not to use git reset?

Tags: git, azure-devops

The Visual Studio Team Service documentation for git:
[link to vsts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/undo?tabs=visual-studio)
contains a warning not to use git reset

> Don't use reset on branches shared with others. Use revert instead.

My question is why? Git reset does not change the history, revert does.
What is the recomandation not to use git reset on a shared branch?

Comment: *"Git reset does not change the history, revert does."* -- [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) doesn't change the history either.

Comment: You generally don't want to change public commits or reset branches - anyone who has the branch *checked out* would need to make the same changes to "fix" their repository. Reset changes public commits on a branch, revert *adds* a new commit to reverse the changes.

Comment: @DavidBold, The point is, if the changes are pushed to a shared repository, be cautious about using git reset.  If the changes you are resetting are not pushed, then you can use git reset all day and not affect others.

Comment: `git reset <commit>` will reset the HEAD to the specified commit and discard the later commits after the specified commit.While `git revert <commit>` will keep all the original commit and create a new commit to revert the changes from the specified commit. So actually `git reset` change the history and `git revert` does not.

Answer (score 1):

> Git reset does not change the history ...

This is sort of right, but also badly wrong, in a subtle but important way.  In Git, the history *is* the set of commits.  So `git revert`, which creates a *new* commit, adds to the history.  Meanwhile, `git reset`—whicih is a complicated command; we're looking here only at the action it takes with branch names as pointers-to-commits—has no immediate effect on the set of commits actually stored in the repository.  This means that, as you say, `git reset` does not change the history.  *But...*

The subtle point here is how one *finds* the history in a GIt repository.  If we look at a single commit, we find that it has:

- a saved snapshot (a *tree* object hash ID);
- a set of parents (a list of *commit* object hash IDs);
- an author and committer (both being name-email-timestamp triples); and
- a log message: whatever the committer put in.

The second item, the list of parent hashes, is what lets us construct the history—the commit DAG, the **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph of commits.  Given one commit, we find its parent or parents.  Suppose we have a tiny repository with three commits, whose hash IDs are (by some odd miracle) `aaaaaaa...`, `bbbbbbb...`, and `ccccccc...`, and:

- `ccccccc...` has parent `bbbbbbb...`;
- `bbbbbbb...` has parent `aaaaaaa...`;
- `aaaaaaa...` has no parents: it's a / the *root* commit.

Let's shorten the hashes to one uppercase letter for convenience.  This means that we can draw the graph as:

```
A <-B <-C
```

or (if we leave out the directional arrow heads, which always point backwards in Git):

```
A--B--C
```

But: ***how did we find `C` in the first place?***  We found `B` from `C`, and we found `A` from `B`, but *how did we find `C`?*

Git's answer to this is that we find `C` by reading a *branch name* like `master`.<sup>1</sup>  The name `master` stores the hash ID `ccccccc...` in it.

If we use `git reset` to *change* the hash ID stored in `master`, say, to `bbbbbbb...` instead, then we *lose* the ID of `C`.  It's as if `C` never existed, and the graph is now just:

```
A--B   <-- master
```

Commit `C` is gone, erased from history.

Git secretly saves it, keeping `C`'s ID saved in the *reflog* for `master`, and in the reflog for `HEAD` as well.  This reflog entry sticks around for 30 days by default (though it's configurable, not only how long but whether reflogs even exist).  Once the reflog entry expires, though, the commit is unprotected, and an eventual `git gc` will find commit `C` in the repository, find that it is *unreachable* from all branch and other such names, and eliminates `C` from the repository—and now it's truly gone.

So `git reset` *can* change the (accessible) history, and can eventually (after reflog expiry) mean that some history—one or more commits—vanish entirely.

Using `git revert` adds a new commit to the history, making the current branch name point to the newly-added commit.  The new commit points back, through its parent ID, to the previous branch tip.  So this never destroys any existing history, it only adds new history—a new commit.

Git is, in general, built for adding new commits.  Git makes this easy and convenient.  It's *not* built for removing existing commits; Git can make this quite painful and difficult, once the commits have escaped your own local repository.  (Until that point, it's still pretty easy, and—because of the reflogs—generally fairly safe as well.)

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, Git finds them through *references*.  Branch names are one particular form of reference.  Tag names are another, and remote-tracking names like `origin/master` are a third.  There are six or so built-in "well known" reference name spaces in Git: branches (`refs/heads/*`), tags (`refs/tags/*`), remote-tracking names (aka remote-tracking "branches" but this is not a good name—these are in `refs/remotes/*`), notes (`refs/notes/*` for `git notes`), replacements (`refs/replace/*` for `git replace`), and `refs/stash` for the stash.

Note that Mercurial, which otherwise has a lot of similarities to Git, has a very different answer to how we find branch tip commits.  No names are necessary to find these commits, in Mercurial.

Comment: Notes and replace? I’ve never heard of these. Good to know and learn.